# Skip the name and phone number screen in Dhee.ai web widget

Tags: javascript, conversational-ui

I've embedded the widget script. When I click the chat icon, I don’t want to see this screen. Can you help me remove it?

[image]

Comment: Without the code that generates this, no we can't help you.

Comment: its a script delivered from dhee.ai thats embeddedt to my site. Sreekumar's answer works.

Comment: @Bergi perhaps I wrongly tagged this as a JS question. Cannot find dhee.ai tag.

Comment: I suppose there is none. dhee.ai support issues are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: dont know. they are a public platform. may be more people soon with these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done like this -

1. Go to Bot settings -> Advanced Settings
2. Search for the property "SKIP_USER_RECOGNITION" and set the value to "yes".
3. Deploy

If you refresh the page where the widget is embedded you will be seeing that it skips the entry screen now.